# How to hide sensitive data when using Android clipboard?

Tags: android, passwords, clipboard, sensitive-data, android-tiramisu

In Android API 33, when you copy something to clipboard, a special bar appears:

[image: The clipboard bar]

If the copied data is sensitive, you can set ClipDescription.EXTRA_IS_SENSITIVE to true for the clip:

```
        PersistableBundle persistableBundle = new PersistableBundle();
        persistableBundle.putBoolean(ClipDescription.EXTRA_IS_SENSITIVE, true);
        clip.getDescription().setExtras(persistableBundle);
```

As a result, the copied data becomes hidden:

[image: Hidden text in the clipboard bar]

However, when you click the share button on that bar or use the copied text in another app, the text is revealed:

[image: Sharing copied text using the clipboard bar]

Or

[image: Sensible data is visible on the top of the soft keyboard]

The question is how to hide sensitive data in this scenario?

Comment: It's behaving exactly as doc specifies. If user copies sensitive data and decides to share or paste it in another app there isn't much that you can do aside from preventing copying in the first place.

Comment: Well, if nothing can be done, it looks like a bug to me. Hiding the data from the bar but revealing it from the same bar immediately in the next step is a bit strange behavior.

Comment: The sense in hiding the data is to prevent others who can view the screen but not access the phone from getting the sensitive data.

Comment: @Robert, that's what I'm talking about: The sense in hiding the data is to prevent others who can view the screen. See my image 2 - the data is hidden, then I click the Share button, and on the next image that data is revealed. I need the data to be hidden all the way from my app to where it will be pasted

Comment: If you need that, you need to not support copy paste, and roll your own only within your app.

Comment: Sensitive data should not be shared, if the user does it anyway then this is the user's choice.